# How to create a new line when only using \n with variables rather than printed text?

Tags: python

I am using Python for reference.
I am trying to create a new line when displaying name, address, city, state, and zip code. However, when I do this, IDLE tells me that "unexpected character after line continuation character". My code is as follows:

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
address = input('What is your street address? ')
city = input('What city do you live in? ')
state = input('What state do you live in? ')
zip_code = input('What is your zip code? ')
print(name\naddress)
```

I know that I can print each thing separately but I want to know how I can print the result using one print function. I know I can do it if I were to have simple text such as:
print('You have to\nshow up to class')

I am basically looking for the code to result as follows:

firstName lastName (first line)

address (second line)

city, state zip-code (third line)

Is there any way to input new lines before variables?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do all my print statements using f-strings. It solves both the problems you stated

Example: Newline:

```
print(f"{name}\n{address}")
```

Example: No spaces:

```
print(f"{city},{state},{zip_code}")
```

Is this what you are looking for? The f-strings can be manipulated for many such variations of how you want your print output to look like.

UPDATE 1: With custom function or string concatenation

If you want to do this without using f-strings and conventional print function approach you can create your own custom print function. Here's just one of the many ways:

```
def prettyprint(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

prettyprint(name, address)
```

Or you can add a new line while obtaining the input for you variables like so,

```
name = input('What is your name? ') + '\n'
print(name+address)
```

Or finally just combine it during print as,

```
print(name+'\n'+address)
```

> Not sure if any of this is what you need but thought will provide a
> few more options for you to explore.

Comment: I haven't learned f strings just yet but thank you anyway! I don't think f works on Python the same as it does with other programming languages so it didn't affect my code. As for the second part, I figured it out! By putting in print(city+',', state, zip_code), I was able to omit that annoying extra space and keep it to the correct format.

Comment: print(name,'\n', address). Shouldn't it be done like this? (for your error)

Comment: Also maybe there is no way to new line with just variables, it seems that the way you said is the only way. I suppose my prof expected us to put in print 3 different times for 3 different lines, but I just wanted to see if there was a more efficient way. Thank you again!

Comment: What do you mean with variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting:

```py
print("{}\n{}\n{}, {} {}".format(name, address, city, state, zip_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem solution i have solved. If you want to use just one print function to print all over the statement you have to use **`f""#(f string)`**. with \n and for spacing use \t.

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
address = input('What is your street address? ')
city = input('What city do you live in? ')
state = input('What state do you live in? ')
zip_code = input('What is your zip code? ')
print(f"Name:{name}\nAddress:{address}\nCity:{city}\nState:{state}\nZip code:{zip_code}\n")
print(f"{city}\t{state}\t{zip_code}")

output:
Name:Elon
Address:25 sampur
City:Washington D.C
State:Alaska
Zip code:99501

Washington D.C  Alaska  99501
```

Sorry for random Address